# Unable to Connect to AWS Keyspace using a particular region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-keyspaces

I am able to connect to aws keyspace using ap-south-1 but when I change it to us-east-2 it says
**"NoHostAvailable('Unable to connect to any servers', {'3.12.23.133:9142': OperationTimedOut('errors=None, last_host=None')})"**

I am using python for connection

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sUsername = '******-at-43*****6380240297'
    sPassword = '********'
    sUrl = 'cassandra.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'
    sSSLCertPath = 'C:\\Users\\KArora\\Downloads\\sf-class2-root.crt'
    sPort = 9142
    session = getDBClient(sUrl, sUsername, sPassword, sPort, sSSLCertPath)

def getDBClient(sURL, sUserName, sPassword, sPort, sSSLCertPath):
    error = ""
    try:
        ssl_context = SSLContext(PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
        ssl_context.load_verify_locations(sSSLCertPath)
        ssl_context.verify_mode = CERT_REQUIRED
        auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username=sUserName, password=sPassword)
        sConn = []
        sConn.append(sURL)
        cluster = Cluster(sConn, ssl_context=ssl_context, auth_provider=auth_provider, port=sPort)
        session = cluster.connect()
        #error += "Success"
        return session
    except Exception as e:
        #error += "Failure"
        return str(e)
```

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Keyspaces requires that SSL is enabled for connections to ensure strong security. The SSL parameter might be missing if you receive that error. To resolve this error you can add the `--ssl`flag to your to your cql connection command. We've listened to our customers and we've created [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/troubleshooting.connecting.html) to help if you run into connection issues.